# Background image disappearing after 2nd call to Codeigniter View

Tags: php, css, html, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter.
I have set a background image for my home page.
Now what happens is this that when I hit the home controller,a view is called and it works fine, but when I try to recall the view explicitly in from another function , the background image disappears and everything else remains on its spot.

This is what i have on the top of my header_view, background image is called from here.

```
<html lan="en">
<head>    
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("public/img/back1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
</style>
```

This is my controller `index()` function which is called automatically when controller is hit.

```
public function index() { 
    $this->load->view('home/inc/header_view');
    $this->load->view('home/home_view');
    $this->load->view('home/inc/footer_view');
}
```

This works fine every time I hit controller.

Below one another function of my controller which I call explicitly, it also calls the view same as the index function does, but in output the background image is missing.

```
public function get_user() {
    $this->load->view('home/inc/header_view');
    $this->load->view('home/home_view');
    $this->load->view('home/inc/footer_view');
}
```

I don't understand what the issue is as index() function which is called automatically when i hit controller does the same thing as get_user() function, but why output is not correct in get_user(). Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To keep the relative links from changing every time you go to a different page, you need to autoload the uri helper and wrap your style and script urls with `base_url()` like this:

```
background-image: url("<?php base_url('relative/path/to/image.img'); ?>");
```

Comment: background-image: url("<?php base_url('relative/public/img/back1.jpg'); ?>")
This is what I did, now it is not showing image anywhere.

Comment: you don't need to include 'relative', just the path to your image from the site root. `base_url()` provides `http://example.com/` and whatever is in the parenthesis comes after that, so saying `base_url('public/img/back1.jpg');` should give you `http://example.com/public/img/back1.jpg`

Comment: Put it back to `background-image: url("public/img/back1.jpg")`, then view the source code on both pages to see the output of both of them to see what changes... when you load `index()`, the URL is `example.com/index.php/controller`, but on `get_user()` is `example.com/index.php/controller/get_user`, which will break the relative URLs in your styles... you want to see which one is working and then make that URL the same every time.

Comment: Basically, when you're on `example.com/controller`, you're pointing to an image at `example.com/controller/public/img/back1.jpg`, but when you're on `example.com/controller/get_user`, you're pointing to an image at `example.com/controller/get_user/public/img/back1.jpg`, which is not the same thing... maybe try `site_url('public/img/back1.jpg')`?

Answer (score 1):

set baseurl at your application\config\config.php file like this

```
 $config['base_url']    = 'http:/example.com/';//make sure it is your main path
```

now change the body style like this

```
background-image: url("<?php echo base_url();?>public/img/back1.jpg");
```

Make sure you have folders like `public/img` and the image is there back1.jpg
Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

use base_url() function [Read more](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)